# Handle FCM notification click

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there possible to handle click on FCM notification which created by android (it happens when application receive push in background). I saw this [one of possible way solve this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42480002/findout-when-firebase-message-recieved-when-app-in-background).[image]  In [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options) i found one interesting moment (see picture). So, how i can make it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase (FCM): open activity and pass data on notification click. android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181654/firebase-fcm-open-activity-and-pass-data-on-notification-click-android)

Comment: I've finally found solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181654/firebase-fcm-open-activity-and-pass-data-on-notification-click-android

Answer (score 0):

We can do a hack.I don't know it's a proper method.But it works !!

Do the below check inside the onCreate Method on the Activity which is opening on the notification click.

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
if(java.lang.Integer.toHexString(getIntent().getFlags()).equals("14000000")) 
{
  //Activity is launched from the notification created by android
}
}
```

For other cases where notifications are created in our FirebaseMessagingService class. You can pass an intent extra and check if it is present in the activity onCreate Method